# I am not able to logout from my WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, debugging, logging, logout

I run a local classified that runs on WordPress with the Classiera theme, due to user demand, I created a local language version of the site, to sync users between the native language and the English version so that it feels like they are on the same platform whenever they switch back and forth, I made the two sites share one database, cutting the long story short, all things work well for both i.e, user sync, plus the ability to automatically update the user roles and details whenever users do so.

That has been the case for the past 3yrs. And even now, jumping through the different platforms shows all is fine.

The problem I have is, an abrupt misbehaving was reported a few days back by one of the site's users that he wasn't able to log out from his account. Whenever he tries, it takes him to:

**https://sitename.com/wp-login.phpaction=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com&_wpnonce=5ae4ad7b7d**

I suggested clearing browser data on his PC but in vain. I also suggested that he switches to the local language side so he can log out but still, the same would happen on the local language site.

So, I embarked on investigating the issue by trying the following:

1. deleted the .htaccess file and Saved changes in the site's general parmalinks settings,
2. Tried troubleshooting for incompatible plugins by renaming them via FTP,
3. Did the same for the theme,
4. added the following code;

```
// Redirect WordPress Logout to Home Page
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
};
```

to the theme's functions.php file. All haven't resolved the issue.

The logout brings you to:

**https://sitename.com/wp-login.phpaction=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com&_wpnonce=5ae4ad7b7d**

If you type the site's url in the browser bar and reload, it still shows am signed in.

What might be the problem?

Tried troubleshooting with the four steps mentioned above but failed to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the url if it is correct?

https://sitename.com/wp-login.phpaction=logout&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com&_wpnonce=5ae4ad7b7d

seems there is missing '?' after login.php.